# How can I get the host URLs from a list of URLs submitted

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a list of URLs submitted by users. I want to make sure: list has no White-spacing, and it contains only host values
i.e site.com,subdomain.site.com,site2.com,site3.net

I have the following code at the moment

```
var list = document.getElementById( "list" ).value ;
```

Taking out the white spaces in list

```
$vars = array_map('trim', explode(',', $list));
```

is $list ok here? I am a newb and not sure the diff b/w $ and var

making sure list only contains host values of the intended URLs (from php manual)

```
function getHost($list) { 
   $parseUrl = parse_url(trim($list)); 
   return trim($parseUrl[host] ? $parseUrl[host] : array_shift(explode('/', $parseUrl[path], 2))); 
}
```

This would only work for one address at a time, can some one help me to make it work for the whole list? Need to iterate this method through the comma separated list

Appreciate all your help.

Comment: You should quote the array keys properly.

Comment: Your first line of code looks like javascript, the rest like PHP. How do both languages come together? Are you doing an AJAX request or something?

Comment: Yes I have declared following before these functions <script>
 var http = createRequestObject();
 var objectId = 'ajaxOutput';

Answer (score 0):

You already used `array_map` here:

```
$vars = array_map('trim', $vars = array_map('trim', explode(',', $list));
```

You can do so as well with your `getHost` function (I changed the variable naming a bit):

```
function getHost($url) { 
   $parseUrl = parse_url(trim($url)); 
   return trim($parseUrl[host] ? $parseUrl[host] : array_shift(explode('/', $parseUrl[path], 2)));
}

$vars = array_map('getHost', explode(',', $list));
```

Job done. The function is applied to each member of the array that is created out of `$list`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = document.getElementById( "list" ).value ;
```

is JavaScript which is executed on the client before the user sends the form data to the server.

```
$vars = array_map('trim', explode(',', $list));
```

is PHP which is executed on the server either before the form is send from the server to the client or after the client has send the form data to the server (or both).

This mean the two lines are only remotely related. `$list` should be `$_POST['list']` or `$_GET['list']`, depending on whether the form method is GET or POST.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Is there a way that I can clean up the list as wanted before sending it to the database? Perhaps using JavaScript? Atm I send the unprocessed list to the database and clean it up using php as clients request "list". more efficient method is to just store the cleaned up list in the first place.